# Force child div to take 100% of parent height

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I am designing a fluid layout (no fixed px, all in %)

I have the HTML as;

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="fl child"><a class="prev"></a></div>
</div>
```

If I check in Firebug, the height of parent is calculated as 400px..But if I give child as height:100%, it does not take the entire height..

How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you add the CSS ? How the 400px is calculated ?

Comment: That is just based on the content it has..i have not added any fixed px value anywhere..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately heights don't work so well with percentages, you can take a look at the min-height css property but you may need to employ some javascript.